# Run vagrant up with highest VirtualBox version

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, vagrant

I've already installed VirtualBox version 4.1.18_Ubuntu from this source:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal contrib
```

**Apparently** the above source was used to install VirtualBox 4.2 which was automatically removed when I installed the vagrant. So, I suppose that the current installed version is from the default Ubuntu source.

When I installed the vagrant (from the default Ubuntu 12.10 source) and tried to run my box with `vagrant up` I got this error message:

```
Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed
that is not supported. Please install one of the supported versions
listed below to use Vagrant:

4.0, 4.1
```

Is there any way to run vagrant with my VirtualBox? Installing newest vagrant version could be also as a solution (the current one: 1.0.3).

I tried: `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox* virtualbox-4.2 vagrant` and `sudo apt-get install vagrant`, it didn't help.

Comment: You installed VirtualBox for 12.04, and vagrant for 12.10. Don't you want to use a compatible version? Or was that a typo?

Comment: Just changed the source to: `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal contrib` apt-get update && apt-get upgrade - Nothing changed. The version of VB remain the same, and the error message is too. Thanks any way.

Comment: To know the version of VirtualBox, run `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox`

Comment: Already tried with 4.1.18_Ubuntu, 4.2 and now I'm installing 4.1 from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian source. Will see what happens

Comment: Use dpkg and report on both VirtualBox and vagrant versions. FYI, I tried on a ubuntu 12.04 32 bit machine with VirtualBox 4.2. Doing apt-get install of vagrant, uninstalled VirtualBox 4.2. When all done, I ended up with vagrant 1.0.1-1 and VirtualBox 4.1.12. I did an init for precise32 and then up. Maybe you could remove VirtualBox and install vagrant and let it pick the matching VirtualBox?

Comment: It worked after installing VirtualBox 4.1 from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian. Unfortunately I can't make it work with Ubuntu's native sources. Mine is Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

Comment: Had the same error on a fresh 14.04. Nothing worked. [Remove **everything** and follow these guidelines](http://www.olindata.com/blog/2014/07/installing-vagrant-and-virtual-box-ubuntu-1404-lts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this same problem, I purged the Ubuntu virtualbox packages, and added lines to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
#Virtualbox
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal contrib
```

Update the apt listings:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the headers for your kernel if they're not installed (because virtualbox install needs them):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Install virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
```

Download and install the latest .deb for vagrant, and all works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here that making this confusing:

- VirtualBox packages from the Ubuntu repository have different names to the packages from the Oracle repository.
- When you install a package, Ubuntu automatically installs additional recommended packages unless you specify the `--no-install-recommends` option.
- There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vagrant/+bug/1125097) affecting the Vagrant package which means it replaces the Oracle VirtualBox packages with the Ubuntu packages when installed.

I suggest that you:

1. Purge all your Vagrant and VirtualBox packages as you describe in your question.
2. Install the latest Oracle VirtualBox package as you did originally.
3. Install the latest Vagrant package from http://downloads.vagrantup.com/, paying attention to which additional packages it tries to install or remove, and specifying `--no-install-recommends` if necessary.